# fit a scatter plot with Weibull curve with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, weibull

I'm not sure if this is duplicate question. But I really hope to get help from here.

I want to plot a graph like in the attachment below, fitting a 2-parameters Weibull curve. The x-axis is `days` and y-axis is `biomaker level`, with a cut off is 0.5.

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrXng.png)

This is a sample data.

```
`biomaker level`    days    result
1.5515  81  Positive
0.712   5   Positive
1.831   15  Positive
1.738   30  Positive
1.519   9   Positive
1.2145  21  Positive
2.2085  19  Positive
2.15    18  Positive
2.1845  20  Positive
2.248   18  Positive
2.098   14  Positive
2.2645  36  Positive
2.273   55  Positive
2.213   9   Positive
2.2515  15  Positive
2.245   14  Positive
1.894   68  Positive
2.265   25  Positive
2.2305  25  Positive
1.7955  84  Positive
1.649   85  Positive
1.4635  16  Positive
1.3775  98  Positive
1.008   114 Positive
1.44    35  Positive
0.1845  2   Negative
```

I have tried this [solution](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotting-2-weibull-curves-in-a-single-plot-using-nls2-and-ggplot2/97751) but I don't know what the initial values are. It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819201/fitting-weibull-function-and-parameter-estimates) is possible, but what does "127" mean in:
`nls(y~127*dweibull(x,shape,scale), start=c(shape=3,scale=100))`? How can I get this constant from my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that question, `127` is sum of `y`. But in some reply, it saying that approach have some issues and provide an expedient way. There exist two ways, `SSweibull` and `dweibull`.

## 1. `SSweibull`

```
df1 <- df1 %>% arrange(days)
x <- df1$days
y <- df1$biomaker.level
yy <- cumsum(y) #max(yy) = 46.0095 ~ 46
nls(yy ~ SSweibull(x, Asym, Drop, lrc, pwr))

Nonlinear regression model
  model: yy ~ SSweibull(x, Asym, Drop, lrc, pwr)
   data: parent.frame()
  Asym   Drop    lrc    pwr 
41.698 44.194 -5.675  1.783 
 residual sum-of-squares: 154.5

Number of iterations to convergence: 10 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.941e-06

plot(yy ~ x)
curve(SSweibull(x, 41.698, 44.194, -5.675, 1.783), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

## 2. `dweibull`

```
nls(y ~ 46 * dweibull(x, shape, scale), start = c(shape = 3, scale = 20))

Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 46 * dweibull(x, shape, scale)
   data: parent.frame()
 shape  scale 
 2.375 23.378 
 residual sum-of-squares: 27.93

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.33e-06

plot(y ~ x)
curve(46 * dweibull(x, 2.375, 23.378), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: May I have few more questions? 
1. why perform nls first rather dweibull to generate shape and scale?
2. where does 46, shape = 3 and scale = 20 come from?

Comment: @NgWingKwan As you compare the `nls` result with code to draw graph, that `nls` is performed beforehand to obtain parameters.

Comment: If my real df has ~4k records, would it "46" change?

Comment: @NgWingKwan `46` in my code and `127` in other code, it's sum of `y`.

Comment: How do you determine "start = c(shape = 3, scale = 20)" in nls with dweibull?